# SQL query to get address city change on a date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query to find out the address details of an employee

```
Person_number           country     town/city   start_Date          end_date
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10                      CA          Toronto     01-feb-2022         10-feb-2022
10                      CA          Ottawa      11-feb-2022         31-dec-4712

11                      CA          Toronto     10-feb-2022         31-dec-4712

12                      AB          Greenvilee  15-feb-2022         20-feb-2022
12                      AB          Portvilee   21-feb-2022         31-dec-4712

13                      CA          North york  01-feb-2022         09-feb-2022
13                      CA          Waterloo    10-feb-2022         31-dec-4712
```

I want I want to create a query to get the data only for those employees whose town/city value has changed within the parameter date.

For example: if I pass the parameter date as 01-feb-17-feb 2022, I should get the following output:

```
Person_number           country     current_town    previous_town   effective_date_ofchange
10                       CA          Toronto            Ottawa          11-feb-2022 
13                       CA          North york         Waterloo        10-feb-2022
```

person #11 will not come as there is no change within the date. Person#12 will not come as the change is after the parameter date.

Can this be achieved with any analytical function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach, with the `LAG` window function:

[The fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4e5e8f959372bbba0f904f95974fb5fa)

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY';

WITH xdata (person_number, country, town_city, start_date, end_date) AS (
        SELECT 10,  'CA',   'Toronto'   ,  '01-feb-2022', '10-feb-2022' FROM dual UNION
        SELECT 10,  'CA',   'Ottawa'    ,  '11-feb-2022', '31-dec-4712' FROM dual UNION
        SELECT 11,  'CA',   'Toronto'   ,  '10-feb-2022', '31-dec-4712' FROM dual UNION
        SELECT 12,  'AB',   'Greenvilee',  '15-feb-2022', '20-feb-2022' FROM dual UNION
        SELECT 12,  'AB',   'Portvilee' ,  '21-feb-2022', '31-dec-4712' FROM dual UNION
        SELECT 13,  'CA',   'North york',  '01-feb-2022', '09-feb-2022' FROM dual UNION
        SELECT 13,  'CA',   'Waterloo'  ,  '10-feb-2022', '31-dec-4712' FROM dual
     )
   , xtable (person_number, country, town_city, start_date, end_date) AS (
        SELECT person_number, country, town_city
             , to_date(start_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
             , to_date(end_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
          FROM xdata
     )
   , table2 (person_number, country, current_town, prev_town, start_date) AS (
        SELECT person_number, country, town_city
             , LAG(town_city) OVER (PARTITION BY person_number ORDER BY start_date)
             , start_date
          FROM xtable
     )
SELECT * FROM table2
 WHERE current_town <> prev_town
   AND start_date BETWEEN DATE'2022-02-01' AND DATE'2022-02-17'
;
```

`LAG(x) OVER (PARTITION BY person_number ORDER BY start_date)`

This obtains the prior `x` for each row for the corresponding person, based on the `start_date` order.

The result:

| PERSON_NUMBER | COUNTRY | CURRENT_TOWN | PREV_TOWN | START_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | CA | Ottawa | Toronto | 11-FEB-2022 |
| 13 | CA | Waterloo | North york | 10-FEB-2022 |